# How do I update a database via jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have recently started to learn jquery to run a game of mine (to get experiance) and I'm currently using a autorefresh on the page, this works fine until I wish to update the mysql server, how do I do this?

The method I used before jquery was simply having a player push a button which would load a new page, on this new page the PHP code would update the database and then reload the game page with the new data from the database. So the new method would be to simply update the database with a push of a button.

James

Comment: Submit a form? Use ajax? You don't provide many details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
var 1 = 'foo';
var 2 = 'bar';

$.post("scripts/php/write_to_db.php", {name: foo, email: bar}, function(data){

 ---handle echoed response from php script here---

});
```

You'd then catch the $_POST['name'] and the $_POST['email'] in your php script, the url for which I've invented in this example.

If you need more clarification, let me know...

Scott

Answer (score 1):

You would still use a server-side language (like PHP that you are used to), to access the database. You will use jQuery to make an AJAX-call, sending the data you want to save to a PHP-file, which in turn validate and sanitize it and then write it to DB.

You can use [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), to send the data through a HTTP POST request, or you can use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) if you need more flexibility.

**A very simplified example:**

```
$.post("/my-file-that-access-the-db.php", {
   someVariable: "some data"
});
```

In your PHP-file you could then access the data like with any other HTTP POST request:

```
$_POST["someVariable"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You still would need the PHPscript, but instead call the php to update the db with ajax/jQuery

```
$.get('update.php',data);
```

Or $.post of course...

Comment: A `GET` request must be idempotent and not have any side effects - `POST` is right for creating resources, then `PUT` for updating them.

Comment: Sure but depending on what he want to do with the db get or post could be used...

Answer (score 0):

As I know, jquery is a javascript based function-set for web, and nothing about MySQL support in javascript... you should try to handle it with PHP (in WEB environment), or some other language executed in server-side.

If you want to get/post a php script from a jquery, you can use: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

goodluck!

Comment: Thanks for the link, will check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a client side language and therefore you cannot update the database via jquery.

You will need to post to a php file that does the update for you. The post can be done by $.post or $.get

Comment: jQuery is a library and not a language.